# Why do I get error if I do not manually process cube dimensions first?

Tags: ssas

In an Analysis Services project, after making some changes I go to reprocess the cube and get "attribute key not found" errors almost every time.  The solution has been to process the dimensions first and then process the cube.  It seems that if any data has changed in the source tables during processing then an error is produced.

Shouldn't processing the cube process the dimensions first automatically?  I changed the processing order in Settings to Sequential and that did not help.

Is having to manually process the dimensions first normal, or is there a different way to go about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you will get the behavior you need if you process the AS Database instead of just processing the cube which would only update the molap partitions for the associated measure groups. otherwise verify that you are performing a process full

Comment: I changed the processing option from Process Full to Process Data in the Process Cube dialog box (I hadn't actually noticed that dropdown before).  And then did a Process Full after that.  That works.  I'm not sure if that is any different than what I was doing before (processing just the cube dimensions first); but technically, that answers my question.  Thanks!